# Swift COW thread safety

Tags: swift, multithreading, copy-on-write

I am looking how copy-on-write works in swift. And little bit confused by `isKnownUniquelyReferenced` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2429905-isknownuniquelyreferenced). Especially by this section:

> If the instance passed as object is being accessed by multiple threads simultaneously, this function may still return true. Therefore, you must only call this function from mutating methods with appropriate thread synchronization. That will ensure that isKnownUniquelyReferenced(_:) only returns true when there is really one accessor, or when there is a race condition, which is already undefined behavior.

So imagine case.

1. We have COW structure without synchronization inside.
2. Class which own instance of this structure and guard it with locks
3. Getter for this structure
4. And want to return copy from this getter thread safely

---

```
import Foundation

class StorageBuffer {
    var field: Int = 1

    init(_ field: Int) {
        self.field = field
    }

    func copy() -> StorageBuffer {
        return StorageBuffer(field)
    }
}

struct Storage {
    private var _buffer = StorageBuffer(1)

    var field: Int {
        get {
            return _buffer.field
        }
        set {
            if !isKnownUniquelyReferenced(&_buffer) {
                _buffer = _buffer.copy()
            }

            _buffer.field = newValue
        }
    }
}

class StorageAware {
    private var _storage = Storage()
    private let _storageGuard = NSLock()

    var storage: Storage {
        _storageGuard.lock()
        defer {
            _storageGuard.unlock()
        }

        return _storage
    }
}
```

Since the real copying will happen later. Is it enough to synchronize getter? Is it necessary or structs is thread safe themselves in this case?
Is any complete doc about swift thread safety anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

CoW structs are as thread safe as an `Int`, i.e. they are not atomic. So just like you have to lock concurrent access when modifying an Int, e.g.

```swift
lock.lock()
var myInt = _storedInt // lock required, not an atomic op
lock.unlock()
myInt += 1
```

you have to do the same when *copying* the CoW struct (you don't show whether your `_storage` itself is ever modified, though it is marked as `var`, so that suggests it is - you would need to lock write accesses to `_storage`).

However, when you did this `isKnownUniquelyReferenced` guarantees to return true if the reference is unique.

Wrong:

```swift
var myStorage = _storage // this can race
myStorage.value = 10
```

Right:

```swift
lock()
var myStorage = _storage // properly locked, can't race
unlock()
myStorage.value = 10 // this is safe now
```

The wrong version shows the race the docs are talking about.